# Finding slope of polyline in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, tin, slope

I am using QGIS 2.2 Valmiera to try to find the average slope of a water course. I've drawn in the water course as a polyline over a large number of contour lines (the water course is long with a very large catchment area).  What I've tried to do so far is create a tin file. I've used the Raster > interpolation function using the heights attribute of the contour line shapefile to make the tin and each time I try it gives me a mini-dump error.  I've tried to simplify the geometry (from 392515 to 66801 vertices) but I still just get the mini-dump error.

Is there another way to get the slope of this polyline without having to make a tin file or am I doing something wrong in trying to make the tin?

Comment: There is a [Computing the slope of the roads with QGIS](http://youarealegend.blogspot.it/2012/07/computing-roads-slopes-with-qgis.html) tutorial which might be applied at your case.

Comment: The problem with the tutorial is that they use existing raster data.  I am attempting to make a raster/tin file.

Comment: Have you tried both the interpolation plugin and the module under Raster -> Analysis -> Create grid? And what does your parameters look like in when you run the interpolation?

Comment: No luck, I am using ArcGIS now on another computer and that created a tin file just fine.